# How to get %ERRORLEVEL% from batch file in Ant

Tags: ant

I want to know if its possible to get the return value from batch file in Ant build xml.

My batch file returns `%ERRORLEVEL%` value (batch file returns 2 in my case). I want to know if it's possible to capture this and mark as error in Ant. Below is the code snippet I use:

```
<exec executable = "cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>     
   <arg value="C:\workspace\Build\cross_Compile.bat"/>
 </exec>
```

Currently after the batch file call, build is reported as success always. It looks like Ant is not processing the `%ERRORLEVEL%` or I am not sure. How I can make Ant process the `%ERRORLEVEL%`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [resultproperty](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and [failonerror](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). By default, the errocode is ignored.

```
<property name="Batcherrcode" value="0"/>
<exec executable = "cmd" failonerror="true" resultproperty="Batcherrcode">
  <arg value="/c"/>     
   <arg value="C:\workspace\Build\cross_Compile.bat"/>
 </exec>
<echo message="Error Code:=${Batcherrorcode}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried and i still have value 0 for `Batcherrcode` eventhough batch file returns 2 ( I do a print in the batch file to find out the errorlevel)

Comment: I think if you print in the batch file, the last error code you get is from the print, which was successful.

Comment: If you print your errocode, after the print command, your error code is that of the print command. Do you exit your batch like this: `@exit %ERRORLEVEL%`? Post the batch file please.

Comment: Sorry. This is my  batch file contents `echo %ERRORLEVEL%
echo " done " 
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%`

Comment: delete the this: `echo %ERRORLEVEL% echo " done "` and test again

Comment: no use :-( . it looks like the return variable from command prompt is not sent to ANT. i always have value 0